# Shell command `head` with timeout

Tags: bash, shell, timeout, head

I need to start a `head` command which shall wait for some seconds for input but if none is arriving it shall abort.  The `stdin` must not be closed (as later input shall still be available to other reading processes.

My first approach was using a standard timeout pattern:

```
head & pid=$! ; sleep 2; kill $pid
```

But unfortunately when sent to background the `head` won't read anything from stdin anymore.

The next approach was to do the timeout stuff in the background:

```
(sleep 2; killall head) &
head
```

But this of course will kill all other running `head` processes; to find the right one seems complicated.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: I didn't really get what you are gonna do. what task does the background `head` do?

Comment: The `head` command reads a couple of lines from stdin and prints them to stdout, then exits (without closing the file).

Comment: @Alfe - not really. The head _close_ the file (it's own copy of the file-descriptor, what got after the fork/exec or what is opening itself, or, the kernel removes all file-descriptors associated to head when the head process exit) (not EXACTLY true, but mostly) :)

Comment: Yeah, right, it does not close the fd of its parent, that's what I meant.

Comment: (And I know that it cannot close its parent's fd, I just wanted to stress that I'm going to use the open fd afterwards, so solutions like `a=$(head)` wouldn't help me.)

Answer (score 3):

```
~$ timeout --help
Usage: timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...
  or:  timeout [OPTION]
Start COMMAND, and kill it if still running after DURATION.
```

So you would run `timeout 2 head` to kill `head` after 2 seconds (while producing no output because there is no input to `head`)

Comment: Doesn't work (for my task): `for ((i=0; i<10; i++)); do echo $i; sleep 1; done | { a=$(timeout 5 head); echo "$a"; cat; }` — This only displays `5 6 7 8 9` but with `a=$(head)` alone, i. e. without the `timeout`, it displays `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`.  I guess the timeout aborts the `head` before it outputs anything.

Comment: But somehow I missed the `timeout` command up to now, so thanks for this pointer :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a [named pipe](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-named-pipes-fifos-bash) instead of `STDIN`.

```
mkfifo /tmp/mypipe

head /tmp/mypipe &
pid=$!
sleep 2
kill $pid
```

or kill the PID of the parent script:

```
PID=$$
(sleep 2; kill $PID) &
head
```

Comment: The `head` command I was talking about was suppoed to read from stdin (and that I cannot change).  So I suppose that there should be a `cat > /tmp/mypipe` somewhere in your answer?

Comment: And anyway, using a named pipe might be a workaround, but an ugly one.  I'd have to determine a free name for it, make sure it gets cleaned up afterwards etc.  I think there might be better solutions around.

Comment: Updated my answer with another possible solution. Yet, your whole approach deems me somewhat awkward. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I'm using a program to read text from stdin, determine heuristically the width and height of it and display it in a window (xterm with less running or similar) of this width and height.  Width and height are determined from the head of the text, but in case the input arrives slowly (comes from a slow command), it shall not wait too long to determine the width and height.  It shall start displaying it soon, later arriving text shall be displayed then as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm now using this:

```
for ((i=0; i<1000; i++))
do
  if IFS='' read -t 2 -N 1 a
  then
    echo -n "$a"
  else
    break
  fi
done
```

I read one character at a time because `read` would not tell me what unfinished data it read in case of a timeout.  I could introduce a newline detection as well but in my case a specific amount of bytes does as well.

Comment: And yes, I know that does not answer the question I posted because it does not even facilitate the `head` command anymore ;-)